# How much time do I have to take a decision about an event?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

An event giving me this choice :

1. A rebel stack is popping in one of my province
2. I lose 1 stability point and some gold

I would like to choose option 1, but I want to move my troop before the fight to have the defensive state bonus.

**How much time do I have to take a decision ?**

In other words, how much time I can let the window opened without the game taking an automatic decision for me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least a month, for some events - 2 to 3 months.